# List view with horizontal scroll

Tags: java, android, android-listview, android-scrollview, android-scroll

I am using custom list view with base adapter. The width of row is longer than screen. But I am not getting horizontal scroll bar like automatic vertical scrollbar. Do I need to specify any extra attribute? I tried with putting listview in horizontal scroll view but still no success. How should I achieve this?

Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You might just need to use android:layout_width="wrap_content" in your horizontal scroll. You should also show your XML layout in case it is just some other minor change, like having the list view inside the horizontal scroll view.

As a side note, you won't get a horizontal scroll bar but the views inside the horizontal scroll view will slide left/right if their width is wider than the screen.

Comment: @Graitoid thnx for interest. Putting list view in horizontal scroll view with 'wrap_content', works finally.